# C++ format string step by step

Tags: c++, string, formatting

I've got a problem with formatting some strings because I do not got all arguments at the same time.
This happens because it's a Server <-> Client solution.

My Server sends me a packet with the format "sdd" <- s = string, d = int and so on
and also the arguments in new packets.

My Client receives them and now need to replace the format specifiers in the string (which is currently a static test string) step by step.

Here is the code of my receive function inner the client which needs to convert my string.

```
bool NetworkStream::RecvPacket()
{
    //Grap System 
    TPacket p;
    if (!Recv(sizeof(p), &p))
        return false;

    // Need to load client strings. Examplestring "%d %s are now %s"
    std::string example = "%d %s are now %s";

    // Step through the list.
    for (int i = 0; p.format[i] != '\0'; ++i) {

        switch (p.format[i]) {
            case 'i':
            case 'd':
            {
                int itest;
                if (!Recv(sizeof(int), &itest))
                    return false;

                //TODO: Need to at arg to string
            } break;

            case 'f':
            {
                double dtest;
                if (!Recv(sizeof(double), &dtest))
                    return false;

                //TODO: Need to at arg to string
            } break;

            case 's':
            {
                WORD wSize;
                if (!Recv(sizeof(WORD), &wSize))
                    return false;

                char buf[1024 + 1];
                if (!Recv(wSize, buf))
                    return false;

                buf[wSize] = '\0';

                //TODO: Need to at arg to string
            } break;

            case 'u':
            {
                unsigned int test;
                if (!Recv(sizeof(unsigned int), &test))
                    return false;

                //TODO: Need to at arg to string
            } break;

            case 'l':
            {
                long long ltest;
                if (!Recv(sizeof(long long), &ltest))
                    return false;

                //TODO: Need to at arg to string
            } break;
        }
    }

    bool bEnd;
    if (!Recv(sizeof(bool), &bEnd))
        return false;

    printf(example.c_str());

    return true;
}
```

Here I've got an example how this should work. (The connection, sending and receiving is working fine)
Test string to format: "%d %s are now %s"

1. The Server sends the Client the format like for this static string "dss" <- THIS CAN BE VARIABLE
2. The Client receives the format and now wait's for the next packet (the first argument)
3. The Server sends the first argument like a 5
4. The Client receives the first argument and now need to add it to the string (So the string should be "5 %s are now %s" for now)
5. The Server sends the next argument like "cats"
6. The Client receives the next arg and will add it also to the string (String should be now "5 cats are now %s")
7. The Server sends the next arg "on diet!"
8. Client receives it and add it to the string again (String "5 cats are now on diet!")
9. The Server send the client the boolean to end the arguments for this packet
10. The Client receives the bool and now just ends reciving for this packet and print the string "5 cats are now on diet!"

So how can I handle this step by step "replacement" for format specifiers?

Comment: If not getting all arguments at once is the problem the client could wait until it received all of them and only then process the output.

Comment: It seems to me that the server client issue has nothing to do with the problem of formatting the strings? Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: The problem isn't in the server & client. The problem is just that i do not have all args at once which results by the server & client.

To wait until all data is recived i would need to store the data in some kind of list. Which need to be dynamic in the types to store. Because it can be somekind of datatype int, unsigned int, double, string and long long. I do not want to create some lists for every datatype...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It thought it would be a fun challenge to do this using regular expressions to break up the string.

There's a nice regular expression here for printf parameters, based off the spec:
http://regexlib.com/REDetails.aspx?regexp_id=3363

It uses negative lookbehind though, which `std::regex` doesn't support. I changed it to match the text before the parameter (`([^%]|%%)*`), so it can just use the full text of each match to write to the output.

The class stores the text, a regular expression iterator, and a text iterator. Each time you push a value, it:

- takes the next regular expression match from the iterator
- printf's the match text to the stream with the one argument
- updates the text iterator to be after the match
- increments the regular expression iterator

At the end, the text iterator's position is used to `printf` the remaining characters.

I used `fmt`'s printf, because it can write to a stream, it's compatible, and it's type safe.

```cpp
class piecemeal_printer
{
    static std::regex printf_param;
    std::string template_text;
    std::sregex_iterator param_it;
    std::string::const_iterator text_it;
    std::ostringstream result;

public:
    piecemeal_printer(const std::string& template_text)
        : template_text(template_text)
        , param_it(this->template_text.cbegin(), this->template_text.cend(), printf_param)
        , text_it(this->template_text.cbegin()) { }

    template <typename T>
    void push(T&& parameter)
    {
        if (param_it == std::sregex_iterator())
        {
            throw std::runtime_error("no more parameters");
        }
        fmt::fprintf(result, param_it->str(), std::forward<T>(parameter));
        text_it += param_it->length();
        ++param_it;
    }

    std::string get()
    {
        fmt::fprintf(result, std::string(text_it, template_text.cend()));
        return result.str();
    }
};

std::regex piecemeal_printer::printf_param(R"re(([^%]|%%)*%([\-\+0\ \#])?(\d+|\*)?(\.\*|\.\d*)?([hLIw]|l{1,2}|I32|I64)?([cCdiouxXeEfgGaAnpsSZ]))re");
```

Then, to use:

```cpp
piecemeal_printer p("The %s is %2.f%% empty");
p.push("glass");
p.push(25.3);
std::cout << p.get(); // The glass is 25.3% empty
```

Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/TUcbhL

--

If c++17 is available to you, and you want to save some unnecessary copying, change the following:

- `param_it->str()` 
  to 
  `std::string_view(template_text.data() + param_it->position(), param_it->length())`
- `std::string(text_it, template_text.cend())` 
  to 
  `std::string_view(&*text_it, template_text.cend() - text_it)`

Comment: i really like this solution. But i do not get it working on my project, because something fails on the printf of fmt.

https://puu.sh/EOmOT/d91e132ef8.png

(Sorry for all the trouble im making. But im kinda new to c++...)

Comment: No worries at all. What version of Visual Studio are you using? And how did you add fmt to your project?

Comment: VS2019 on v142 and i just loaded the headers into my third_party include dict

Comment: I'm taking a shot in the dark here, but on line 31 of printf.h in trunk includes this: `std::numeric_limits<int>::min()`. I've hit issues using `std::min` because windows.h and other old C headers `#define` min to be a macro. That causes the compiler's preprocessor to swap the token "min" with some expression like `(a>b?a:b)` which makes weird errors. Do you have any headers you're `#include`-ing that might cause this? (if you're including the windows.h, the fix is to add `#define NOMINMAX` before including it)

Comment: I'm not sure. I've searched for the #define MIN. But no results. Also if i add the #define NOMINMAX before the windows.h there are 1000 new errors.

Watch your GitHub. I've done something "special"

Comment: Really? Yikes. Well, in that case you could try fixing fmt by changing that to this: `(std::numeric_limits<int>::min)()` (adding the extra parenthesis) . If it actually works, you could create a pull request to make the same patch in their code. They actually mitigate `std::max` the same way later in the file, they should know better :) https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt/blob/master/include/fmt/printf.h

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I did the changes and added the #define FMT_HEADER_ONLY before the #include <fmt/printf.h> at least now it compiles the binary. But now if it get's to the push func of your code it crashes the binary. 

Here are all calls: https://puu.sh/EPKfc/3885e19b3a.png

Comment: That's a bummer! It looks like it hit some internal error, and then crashed inside its error handler? Do you know (from the debugger or otherwise) what string and value it was trying to format?

Comment: It crash's if i recive a long long (as it try to format it into a %ll or %llu)

Comment: Nvm. It crash's if it get to the .get function. So the string can't be built. Here are the debugger calls: https://puu.sh/EQuU7/f9cd587091.png

Comment: It seems `%ll` is not supported by printf, fmt::printf, or the regular expression. It causes teh regular expression to split in a weird spot, I should look into making that more robust. What happens if you use `%lld` instead?

Comment: I removed the long part and it crashes on the .get function i think this is my core-crash problem.

Comment: Hmm... The only part that it makes sense would crash that is this bit: `std::string(text_it, template_text.cend())`, if it had a mal-formed printf symbol. Is it possible to inspect that content in the debugger or print it out?

Comment: The printf format seems like a pretty simple state machine (no backtracking, DFA-representable), so I tried writing a parser that doesn't throw as much. Now it only invokes `fmt::fprintf` if it encounters a well-formed parameter, and defaults to just printing badly formed parameters. If there's no printf parameter left in the template string, it simply doesn't print the argument now.

Is this version a little more robust? https://godbolt.org/z/byAfQQ

Comment: This works, but %ll wont get printed. Even with the correct data type.

This was my Test String -> fmtStr("%d %.2f are now %s worth %ll gold!");
My Args: 1, 2.0f, "Es funktioniert!", 20000000000
Output: 1 2.00 are now Es funktioniert! worth  gold!

Thank's for your continued support :O Really appreciated!

Comment: %ll doesn't print with regular printf for me: https://godbolt.org/z/bnLEMH . fmt::printf also seems to throw an exception when I pass %ll . %lld prints a very long number.

Comment: Sorry.... I just missed the %lld.... Your totaly right about the format with %ll .

Thanks for your nice work and for your time :) Have nice last days in 2019!

Comment: You to, happy holidays

Answer (score 0):

To build the string, use a [std::ostringstream](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream) object, for example:

```
#include <sstream>
```

...

```
std::ostringstream oss;
```

Replace each of your `//TODO: Need to at arg to string` lines with code to stream the variable you've parsed, for example:

```
oss << itest;
```

Comment: Instead of building the string this just will give me all args in a line....
The Output for my example is now: -330460306  are now @35catsondiet!

Comment: Add spaces to the stream: `<< x << " " << y`, etc.

Comment: @parktomatomi this also won't replace the format specifiers with the args. Just add the args to the end of the to formatting string

Comment: Oh, ok. You might want to edit the question to point out that you already have several string templates and you have to use printf-style formatting because of that, to make it clear to dum-dums like me.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a find and replace on your example string. For example:

```
int itest;

// Get itest's value...

// Add value into string
int index = example.find("%d");
if (index != std::string::npos)
    example.replace(index, 2, std::to_string(itest));
```

This should work okay as long as you are filling in arguments in order.

**EDIT**

To parse a more complicated specifier like `"%.2f"`, the following could work:

```
char buffer[100];
int itest;

// ...

// Handle an "%f" specifier
int start = example.find('%');
if (start != std::string::npos) {
    // Specifier will end with an 'f'
    int end = example.find('f', start + 1); 
    if (end != std::string::npos) {
        // Parse specifier through snprintf
        snprintf(buffer, 100, example.substr(start, end - start + 1).c_str(), itest);
        example.replace(start, end - start + 1, buffer);
    }
}
```

Note this code will assume that the specifier it finds (i.e. the first one in string `example`) is what we want. This should be okay as long as we're working on `example`'s specifiers in order.

Comment: But whats about specifiers like %.2f ? This is really difficult to know because i got over 2000 Strings with specifiers... Sometimes its just %f and sometimes %.2f or %.3f and so on. Any idea about this problem? I really would like to use the normal format specifiers like usually.

Comment: Handling specifiers like %.2f would be a greater challenge. It looks like we could extract the entire format specifier and run it through some printf, but this certainly isn't the most elegant solution. I'm updating my answer with an example of this.